# navigation event in SF1 browser (.app or communities)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, navigation, salesforce1-app

I have created a Lightning component in which I am using navigate event from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_navigateToURL.htm

Now code is similar to

```
gotoURL : function (component, event, helper) {
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": "/006/o"
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

This code works on SF1 app but does not work on communities or .app using the component.

Are there any common methods to navigate in both SF1 and normal communities or apps using the same component??

Thanks
Ray